# Найти и дополнить значение из строки

Tags: php

```
#/reply client-6 — ваш^ответ^клиенту
#/reply client-7 — ваш^ответ^клиенту
#/reply client-7 — ваш^ответ^клиенту

$var = '/reply client-6 — ваш^ответ^клиенту';
```

Как найти вырезать из строки значение **client-***?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

наверное как-то так:

```
$string = '/reply client-6 — ваш^ответ^клиенту';
$pattern = '/(client-\d+)/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string); // /reply  — ваш^ответ^клиенту
```

---

забрать значение так:

```
$string = '/reply client-6 — ваш^ответ^клиенту';
$pattern = '/(client-\d+)/';
preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

**[preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php)**

Comment: Прошу прощения, я имела ввиду его вырезать для дальнейшего использование. Т.е оставить только его, а остальное удалить

Comment: @Евгения через preg_match. см. ответ и доки https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-match.php